# Adding "Interesting Tags" & "Ignored Tags" like StackOverflow.com in a WordPress Blog?

Tags: customization, wp-admin

How to give "Interesting Tags" "Ignored Tags" selection option like stackoverflow.com in a WordPress blog?

If a blog is about lots of topics and I want to give option to user to choose option like

"Interesting Tags" and "Ignored Tags" option of stackoverflow.com.

How to give that facility? Is there any plugin?

Comment: I haven't used those features much yet; can you explain what effect you'd like them to have on your blog? Should ignored tags make it so the user never even sees those posts, does it just affect the tag cloud, or something else?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - yes, same like it works in stackoverflow.com . registered user on SO can and and remove tags upon interest. I want to give the facility of selecting tags of interest. User should only get blog post of selected tags. If any tag is not in a user's favorite tag list then user should never seen those articles.

Comment: @meta-gear-solid - I'm confused. You want a persistent set of interesting tags that will completely filter out everything else the users sees on the external facing view of the blog? What would be the use for "ignored" tags then? Shouldn't we filter out ignored tags and then maybe have a list of posts in a widget that the items with the interesting tags? Or maybe something else?

Comment: I'm looking to do something like this in buddypress but I don't know how. A would then be able to follow tags and only posts from within those tags would show up in the activitystream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SO does not hide the posts (AFAIK), it just highlights or unhighlights them. And I am sure they are basically using CSS classes for that.

From (very) quick look at the source, they basically use tags as CSS classes and then load a unique-to-you javascript that adds styles to entries with those classes.

You basically would need to generate a visitor specific CSS or Javascript which you generate based on the tags. Plus user interface to select/unselect those tags (I don't like the one SO uses). Plus extending WordPress user model to store those preferences.

Not a big project, but a medium size one.

Comment: not a medium too, if you just use cookie ;)